# Tensorflow 2 doesn't recognize all my GPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU with 8GB of VRAM. When I run `nvidia-smi` it shows the following:

```
Sat Jul  2 16:48:34 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 516.59       Driver Version: 516.59       CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   64C    P5    17W /  N/A |      0MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when create a `tf.Variable` it gives the following output:

```
>>> v = tf.Variable(tf.linspace(-10., 10, 100000))
2022-07-02 16:50:54.423148: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2022-07-02 16:50:54.803943: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1510] Created device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 5482 MB memory:  -> device: 0, name: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070 Laptop GPU, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 8.6
```

The question is, where is the rest of my GPU VRAM?

Comment: It's called overhead.  CUDA and other activities use some of your GPU VRAM.

Comment: @Robert this doesn't make sense. When I create the `tf.Variable`, the Task Manager shows that exactly 5.6GB of VRAM is being used. Absolutely nothing else is using the NVIDIA GPU, just TensorFlow.

Comment: Try initializing `tf.variable` with `use_resource=True`

Comment: @Djinn no such argument exists for `tf.Variable`

Comment: Maybe `tf.get_variable_scope().set_use_resource(True)` before any other calls to tensorflow?

Comment: This sounds more likely to be resolved if you file an issue in tensorflow's github, I am not sure we can fix this.

Comment: @Djinn `get_variaable_scope` does not exist in `tensorflow` module. I think it's relevant to point out I'm using TensorFlow 2.6.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy just posted the issue on GitHub, let's see what happens then.

Comment: Ahh, I just tried on my lab computer and also get the same result. Using RTX Titan, I get 16757MB out of 18130MB free (92.4%). I have noticed even without limiting GPU memory, tf doesn't truly use 100% available memory but close enough. I'm used to always limiting memory. Also would like to see how this is resolved. Even when I used `MirroredStrategy()`, both GPUs only use roughly 92% available memory.

Comment: @Djinn that sounds like something is not right. In my case, TensorFlow is using about 70% of the total VRAM, this is giving me problems training some larger models

Comment: Hi @OtávioAugustoSilva, as per the tested build configurations, Tensorflow 2.x is compatible with CUDA 10 upto CUDA 11.2. Please refer [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#gpu) for more information. Thank you!

Comment: Have same problem with Quadro T1000 WSL2, nvidia-smi shows proper 4096MB, when running any code using GPU, I have GPU RAM: 2.0 GB... I tried different configurations, environments with conda etc., nothing helped. Are you using WSL2 or Windows, or Linux?

Answer (score 0):

If your using windows - it's takes and keeps a big hunk for its own use.  Last I checked there was no way to release that memory for TF use.  Linux is the cure.

Windows 11 reserves a portion of GPU memory for system resources and graphics operations, which is known as the GPU reserved memory. This reserved memory is used by the operating system to store system data and graphics operations that are critical to the functioning of the system.

The amount of GPU reserved memory can vary depending on the hardware configuration of the system and the amount of system memory available. Generally, the GPU reserved memory is a fixed percentage of the total GPU memory, which can range from a few megabytes to several hundred megabytes.

One of the key benefits of reserving GPU memory is that it can help prevent system instability and crashes caused by running out of memory. By reserving a portion of the GPU memory, the operating system ensures that critical system data and graphics operations have access to the memory they need, even when the system is under heavy load.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).